# If a shipment contains $5$ defective chips and there are $1000$ chips in the shipment, what is the probability that the shipment will be accepted?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, economics

> A computer manufacturing firm accepts a shipment of CPU chips from its suppliers only if an inspection of $5$% of the chips, randomly chosen from the shipment, does not contain any defective chips. If a shipment contains $5$ defective chips and there are $1000$ chips in the shipment, what is the probability that the shipment will be accepted?

**My Approach** :- I approached the problem like that we just have to choose the $50$ chips from the $995$ good chips and divide it by the no of ways of choosing $50$ chips from $1000$ chips which is :-
$$\frac{\binom{995}{50}}{\binom{1000}{50}}$$

My question is, is this correct? If not, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I agree with your conclusion.